# Find ratio of the volume of the two spheres

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> A cube fits exactly inside a sphere a sphere fits exactly inside the cube. What is the ratio of the volume of the smaller sphere to the ratio of the larger sphere?

Since the only *variable* we need to find the volume of a sphere is the radius of the sphere, my original attempt involved expressing the radius of one sphere in terms of the radius of the second sphere through the cube. Given that the cube fits exactly inside the larger sphere, the direct distance from the center of the to any of the $4$ corners of the sphere will be the radius for the larger sphere, and the perpendicular distance from the center of the cube to any of its sides will be the radius of the smaller sphere. From here, I'm thinking that the next step would involve the use of Pythagora's theorem, but I can't find a way to express the two radii in terms of each other without involving another unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Let $a$ the side of the cube, so the smaller sphere has diameter $a$ and the larger sphere has diameter $a \sqrt3$ (Pythagoras). Since the volume is proportional to the third power of the diameter, you have the ratio of the two sphere's volumes as $3^{3/2} \simeq 5.2$ .

Comment: "The volume is proportional to the third power of the diameter" Is it not proportional to the third power of the radius?

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt yes, this is also true. Since diameter (d) = 2 x radius (r), this will not matter. For two spheres, $r_1^3/r_2^3 = d_1^3/d_2^3$.